# CSS background image doesn't display when hosted

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've been laying the foundations for a website locally and I've just uploaded it to a server. However, now the background images for two divs aren't showing up. Any reason why this is happening?

Website is [here](http://comfyshoulderrest.com/ads/), but snippets of relevant code below for brevity.

Of the four fullscreen divs, one and three should have background images.

HTML

```
<div id="one"></div>
```

CSS

```
#one {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("images/tube2c.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    //border-bottom: 3px solid #CD3333;
}
```

Comment: Press F12 to open the debugger, look at NETWORK, reload the page, look for 404 errors. You probably have the wrong path.

Comment: If I follow the path it shows me the image.

Comment: Try hit `Ctrl+F5`, you can even hold it for few seconds ;)

Comment: On the website you've posted everything seems to work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by ad blockers, your images are stored in a `/ad/` directory whatever adblocker you are using is blocking them.

Disable your adblocker and refresh the page they should load up.

Answer (score 3):

Your image is 4.5mb!!! It works, but it will take an eternity to show up!

Just reduce the image size.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Chrome with `AdBlock Plus` and I had to add the site to my whitelist and then refresh for the background to show up, the Graphic didn't take very long to download for me, but I have a rather fast connection.

Comment: it will take longer on different connection speeds, you should not assume everyone has a fast connection, plus there is no need for a full resolution image on the web unless downloading.

Comment: I only assume that most people have more than dial up speeds. something around 1.5mbs down or more.  that graphic should then only take about 5 seconds, which would still cause an irritation, but it would not take `an eternity`

Comment: 1.5Mbs(megabits) is actually around 187KBs (kilobytes) in the best of circumstances which would take about 24 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Firefox, but not Chrome.

Receiving these errors in Chrome:

- GET http://comfyshoulderrest.com/ads/style.css 404 (Not Found)
  comfyshoulderrest.com/:17
- Refused to execute script from
  'https://raw.github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll/master/jquery.onepage-scroll.js'
  because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
  MIME type checking is enabled. comfyshoulderrest.com/ads/:1
- Refused
  to execute script from
  'https://raw.github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll/master/jquery.onepage-scroll.min.js'
  because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
  MIME type checking is enabled.

### Try:

- Try downloading the files from Github, saving them on your server (with the correct MIME type) so Chrome will work. You can also use rawgithub.com instead.
- Reduce your file size for tube2c.jpg - 17.05 seconds to load on my system
- Also change /ads/ to something else. AdBlockPlus is blocking it it Chrome.
- Make sure your server is setting your MIME types correctly as well. I'm getting "text/html" for style.css.
- Set your DIV to the screen size at max

I also recommend using Firebug in Firefox and Chrome Developer Tools - Just looking at the errors in Chrome Developer Tools showed what it doesn't like.